# Run scheduled tasks on huge mongo items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, cron

I know this might be a broad questions, but I've been trying to find the right way to do this and I don't seem to be going anywhere.

Basically, I have a bunch of Objects saved in mongo that contain events, like below :

```
{

  "date" : "2020-09-09",
  "day" : 1599573600000 // epoch time
  "from" : 1599595200000 // epoch time
  "to" : 1599695200000 // epoch time
}
```

I need to fire some events, like sending a reminded SMS etc, before the date that is specified in `from` field.

I know I can write a cron job and regularly check on my entire mongo collection, find all the ones that are due and the rest is obvious.

However, somehow I feel like there must be a better way, because this can be extremely slow after our database grows with millions of events.

So the question that I have is,

1- What are some other options, beside cron jobs.

2- Is there any difference between running Cron jobs in NodeJS, and running Cron Jobs in Google App Engine ( server-less instance), which one is better?

3- Is there any service out there that anyone has used?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to stay in the GCP ecosystem.

For scalability you could use cron to kick off a Google Dataflow pipeline. With this pipeline you can define a pipeline step to be executed for each record that matches the given query. Dataflow will ramp up the number of workers as it goes to handle the scale.

If you're not at that level of scale, Dataflow can be a bit heavy and may feel like overkill for your current use case. If that's the case, then you can use a combination of cron and google cloud tasks where you'd enqueue/launch a task per record. For large amounts of records, you could launch a task per batch of records (i.e. an injector pattern)
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/manage-cloud-task-scaling#large-scalebatch_task_enqueues

Another option is just using google cloud tasks, using the `'schedule_time'` field. Here you'd enqueue the tasks when you originally write the record into the DB, instead of periodically querying to see which ones need to be run
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks

> 2- Is there any difference between running Cron jobs in NodeJS, and running Cron Jobs in Google App Engine ( server-less instance), which one is better?

I wasn't sure what you meant by your second question because you can run node.js in app engine. In my experience things do work better when you keep everything within GCP.